# Why is the same text content rendered differently in <input> than in <div> or <span> tags?

Tags: html, css

**The Situation**
I have two pages with identical content and styling. The difference between them is that one lists items with `<div>` elements and the other with `<input>` elements (for showing and editing a resource, respectively).

I'd like both pages to have the same layout. I've achieved the layout I want on the standard `<div>` page and would like to duplicate it on the page with `<input>` elements. Both pages have the same CSS rules applied to them as well as Eric Mayer's Reset.

**The Problem**
Text is rendered differently in a `<div>` element than it is in an `<input>` element and results in an `<input>` that is too high.

**What's Been Tried**
I've tried setting the height of the `input` so that it is the same as the `div`, though that causes the text to become clipped at the bottom. I couldn't find a way to remove the white space at the top of the input.

I also did a diff of the computed styles for each element and they are almost identical (aside from a few styles that have no affect on the issue here).

**The Question**
Is there a way to make the `input` in the first picture match the height of the `div` in the second?
Additionally, is there a place where I can learn more about how/why browsers have this sort of behavior and what controls it? I've already read through [W3C's CSS Fonts Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/) with unsatisfactory results.

See current state (`input`, `div`):

[image: <code><input></code> page]

```css
.recipe .header {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #f0424b;
}

.form-recipe input {
  font-family: "futura-pt";
}

.header {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

// Reset

input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline; 
}

// User agent stylesheet

input {
  padding: 1px 0px;  
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px inset;
  border-image-source: initial;
  border-image-slice: initial;
  border-image-width: initial;
  border-image-outset: initial;
  border-image-repeat: initial;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="delicious">
 <form name="recipe.edit" class="form form-recipe recipe">
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="form-row">
    <input type="text" class="header" value="Banana Bread"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

[image: <code><div></code> page]

```css
.recipe .header {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #f0424b;
}

.header {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

// Reset

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline; 
}

// User agent stylesheet

div {
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="delicious">
 <div class="recipe">
  <div class="header">
   Banana Bread
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look up the box model. This has to do with default CSS settings most likely. Looks as though the input has some top/bottom padding whereas the div does not. Look into CSS resets. Without code it's hard to say.

Comment: Browsers apply certain styles by default. you need to reset those styles before applying your own.

Comment: Here you can find Eric Meyer's CSS reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Show your current *code* and state the difference verbally, too. There are several ways in which `input` elements may have special default rendering, but we need to see exactly what you have tried (and managed) to set as well as what the remaining problem(s) is/are.

Comment: As you can see in the pictures, both elements have no padding (well, the input has `padding: 1px`, but that doesn't affect the area I'm concerned about). Those screenshots were taken with Chrome Dev Tools. Margin shows as orange, padding as green, and inner content as blue. I'm concerned about the blue part. I've added some code examples to show what I have currently. I have been using a reset. I also did a diff of the computed styles and they are almost identical. It's also worth noting that I'm using Typekit's "futura-pt" font on the site captured in the screenshots.

Comment: Your example code did not eliminate the padding and the border from the input (at least not in Chrome), partly because the selector in the user stylesheet is more specific. Especially the input has a __2px__ border, although the style is `inset` that might not be that clear visually with the color chosen. Once that is rectified, I don’t see any difference any more, http://jsfiddle.net/be20py0q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/zbhyxdot/)? That works if you want them exactly identical. (The spaces between them are because of the other wrappers)

### HTML

```
<div class="delicious">
    <form name="recipe.edit" class="form form-recipe recipe">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-row">
                <input type="text" class="header" value="Banana Bread"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<!------------------------------------------------------------>

<div class="delicious">
    <div class="recipe">
        <div class="header">
            Banana Bread
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.recipe .header {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #f0424b;
}

.form-recipe input {
  font-family: "futura-pt";
}

.header {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  padding:0;
  outline:0;
}
```

Though I personally wouldn't recommend this, because I believe the user needs to realize that it's now able to edit the contents, anyway, maybe set `outline-color:#f0424b` and focus the element on edit? `outline` does not affect the element's width/height but it does give some clue that you are in focus and able to edit.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Though setting `outline: 0` didn't seem to change the position of the input, setting `border: 0` does. I cant believe I missed that. Additionally, the text in the `<div>` was not positioned to take up the entire height of the `<div>`. I corrected this by changing the `line-height` of that text. 
Regarding recommending having indication on an input field: Yes, completely! I will add different indicators to this form :)